# How to get an element's attribute in a Playwright test?

Tags: javascript, playwright

I'm trying to get an element's attribute in a test. My test looks like this:

```
test(`Should be at least 5 characters long`, async({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('http://localhost:8080');
  const field = await page.locator('id=emailAddress');

  const _attribute = await field.getAttribute('minlength');
  const minlength = Number(_attribute);

  await expect(minlength).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(5);    
});
```

When I run this, I can see that the `minlength` value is `0`. This is because `_attribute` is `null`. However, I don't understand why. `field` is a `Locator`. But, I can't seem to get the attribute or it's value. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that the initial value of `minlength` in your webpage is `5`? Or is it being set dynamically after the page is loaded? To be sure, you can try to change the locator function to evalaute and see how it results. `const _attribute = await page.evaluate(() =>  document.querySelector("#emailAddress").getAttribute("minlength"))`. And log it to see if it still returns `null`.

Comment: @archon Thanks for the response. When I log the result of `await page.evaluable(() => document.querySelector('#emailAddress'));`, I see `null`. I have manually navigated to `http://localhost:8080` to ensure I'm trying to visit a running site (which I am). I also verified that an `input` element with an `id` of `emailAddress` exists on the page. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: My guess is that the `minlength` attribute is set dynamically by javascript, after the webpage is loaded. And what happens is that playwright is picking the element before `minlength` assigned. You can try changing the `page.goto` function with `page.goto(url, { waitUntil: "networkidle" })`. If waiting until networkidle doesn't resolve your issue, you can try putting a manual timeout with settimeout before running the locator method to see if it's caused because of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following worked for me

```
const inputElement = page.locator('#emailAddress');
minLength = await inputElement.evaluate(e => (e as HTMLInputElement).minLength);
```

Answer (score 29):

This is the same but uses a native PlayWright function for getting attribute values

```
const inputElement = page.locator('#emailAddress');
const minLength = await inputElement.getAttribute('minLength');
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [toHaveAttribute](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-attribute)(**Added in v1.20**)

You can combine getting and verifying attribute in single step as below:

```
await expect(locator).toHaveAttribute("minlength", "5")
```

> Note: Using toHaveAttribute is not only short  but more reliable
> code as well being a [auto-retrying assertion](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-assertions#auto-retrying-assertions) which means it will retry
> until the assertion passes, or the assertion timeout is reached .This
> way it can help reduce or eliminate flakiness in tests by waiting until a condition is met.