Playwright: how to interact with Angular Material checkbox
I have an Angular component that contains an Angular Material checkbox:
<mat-checkbox id="my-checkbox">My Checkbox</mat-checkbox> 

My goal is to test the containing application, using Playwright.
Via a Playwright locator, I am able to successfully reference the mat-checkbox. I have attempted to use the locator's check and uncheck functions to explicitly set the checkbox state, but this fails, because mat-checkbox is not an HTML input element.
const checkbox = page.locator('id=my-checkbox');    // OK
await checkbox.check();                             // throws
await checkbox.uncheck();                           // throws

I also tried referencing mat-checkbox's contained <input> element, but this also fails, apparently because the input element is not visible (it is only used internally by Angular Material to implement checkbox functionality).
Using the locator's click function, I am able to toggle the state of the checkbox:
const checkbox = page.locator('id=my-checkbox');    // OK
await checkbox.click();                             // toggles checkbox state

However, I am unsure how to retrieve the current state of the checkbox. The locator's isChecked function fails, in the same manner, for both the mat-checkbox and its contained input element.
This is my first experience using Playwright with Angular Material and I imagine there may be other Material components that similarly encapsulate functionality in a way that prevents easy testing.
Is there a recommended best practice for solving this issue?

When or click on this element, what happens to its attributes?

For people who don't use Angular, can you provide a really simple way to get up and running and test it? A simple package.json, ng init commands? This also pins versions which are often important. Thanks.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097169/1831456

I've run in to this with angular as well. The issue I found is that angular creates the <mat-checkbox> object and then puts an <input type="checkbox> inside of it.
So on the rendered page it looks something like this:
<mat-checkbox id="yourid">
    <input type="checkbox">
</mat-checkbox

If you put the id on the mat-checkbox, it won't register as a checkbox.
You can get around this by using Playwright's nested locator features:
page.Locator("#yourmatcheckboxid").getByRole("checkbox")

Specifically, this looks for your mat-checkbox object, then within that object it looks for another object with a role of checkbox
