How to getProperty in Playwright
I need to get a property from the element.
How do I do that in playwright?
I can do getAttribute but I don't see an option for getProperty?

Properties and attributes are the same. It'd be better if you showed the page you're scraping or testing, provided the expected output and shared your test code so far as a [mcve]. Without all of that, there's no easy way to help.

if you mean arbitrary JS object properties, you'll have to get those using page.evaluate, with the idea being that you're doing browser integration testing: you shouldn't really need access to object properties: you should be testing for on-page results, not internal-JS results (that's what your unit tests are already for)

This question is similar to: How to get attribute value of an element in Playwright Python. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

See this - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78097169/1831456

The question is for playwright-typescript , not python.

you can use the evaluate method to get a property from an element.
const propertyValue = await page.$eval(selector, (element, propertyName) => {
return (element as any)[propertyName];
}, 'propertyName');

